# React onDrag always ends with 0 for screenX/screenY

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following function:

```
_onDrag(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.screenX);
}
```

and I have a div:

```
<div
  draggable="true"
  onDrag={this._onDrag.bind(this)}
  style={{width: "400px", height: "400px", backgroundColor: "red"}}
></div>
```

It seems to work, but the end of each drag the console log (for the position of screenX) is always `0`. Why is that?